# Cannot align or resize graphics

Tags: graphics, scaling

I've search for a solution but cannot determine the problem. I neither resize nor align a graphic. In the preamble I'm including:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[komastyle,automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
```

Here's an example where I try to insert the graphic. The size stays the same and the grahic is aligned to the right.

```
\begin{figure}[htb] \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{pngimagename}
    \caption{text here}
    \label{test}
\end{figure}
```

If you need more code, I will post it. I've searched tex.stackexchange but did not find any solution. Thank you

Comment: Please post full code. BTW `pdftex` is not needed for `graphicx`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.  It is difficult to solve a problem without being able to create it first.

Comment: The problem could be caused by the image itself. Can you make it available for download from somewhere?

Comment: please provide MWE with your graphics

Comment: Put your `\includegraphics{}` inside of `\fbox{}`. This way you'll see the actual size of the image (which can have white padding which was confusing you). Also, be sure to use `pdflatex` to compile.

Comment: I cannot resproduce the error using a minimal example. I've tried to delete all files leaving only the TeX file. But know it works and I don't understand cause I compiled the files several times before checking the pdf.

Comment: So it is solved now? If so, we can delete the question as "too localized"

Comment: Well - yes. It has to be. I cannot determine the cause or give additional informations why this is happening to get help. =( Please delete. Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that the OP has solved, but is unable to identify. Removing auxiliary files seem to have done the trick.